# Subprocess in python3

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python, and I wrote some codes for a simple subprocessing script, but I can not debug the error raised by the interpreter. Here is my code below;

```
import subprocess
import datetime as dt
import sys
import chardet

class SP():
    def execute(self, command, args=""):
        try:
            p=subprocess.Popen(command+" "+str(args),
            shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            print("ID of spawned process is :"+str(p.pid)+"\n")
            out,err=p.chardet.detect(out)
            out=out.decode("utf-8")
            splitted=str(out).split("\\n")
            for o in splitted:
                print(o)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Exception caught :"+str(ex))

obj=SP()
obj.execute("ls")
```

This is the error I get when I run the code;

`Exception caught :'Popen' object has no attribute 'chardet'`

Please can anyone help?

Comment: not sure what `out,err=p.chardet.detect(out)` is meant to do, but you would normally have `out,err=p.communicate()`

Comment: The usage of `chardet` is: `chardet.detect(xxx)` per the [docs](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: `chardet` is not an attribute/method of the module `subprocess`.

Comment: `out,err = chardet.detect(out)` would cause an error: `out` referenced before assignment

Comment: @alaniwi It worked, Thanks!